# How to add diamond marker in the progress bar percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add the diamond marker below to indicate the percentage.

I'm unable to add it. As the color of the progress bar should also change, for example if it's 70% then it should be green and the remaining 30% should be red.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .progress-wrapper {
      background: white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .progress {
      height: 100%;
      width: 60%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      background: #63ed63;
    }

    .progress-label {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }

  </style>

  <div class="progress-wrapper"><div class="progress" style="width:80%"></div><label class="progress-label">80 per cent<label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic version using setInterval:

```js
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
var diamond = document.getElementById("diamond-wrapper");

function init() {
  var loop = setInterval(frame, 15);
  var percentage = 0;

  function frame() {
    if (percentage >= 100) {
      clearInterval(loop);
    } else {
      percentage++;
      updateProgressDOM(percentage);
    }
  }
}

function onProgressInputChange(event) {
  var percentage = event.currentTarget.value;
  percentage = percentage < 0 ? 0 : percentage > 100 ? 100 : percentage;
  updateProgressDOM(percentage);
}

function updateProgressDOM(percentage) {
  bar.style.width = percentage + '%';
  document.querySelector('.bar-text').innerHTML = percentage * 1 + '%';
}
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.bar-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: black;
}

#diamond-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
}

.diamond {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

.diamond:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: lightblue;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" id="progress">
  <div class="bar" id="bar">
    <div id="diamond-wrapper">
      <div class="diamond"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-text"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="init()">Init progress</button>
<br>
<br>
<input min="0" max="100" placeholder="progress value" type="number" onChange="onProgressInputChange(event)">
```

Comment: How I can make it static according to the % ?

Comment: What do you mean by static ? Do you mean to show percentage inside the diamond marker?

Comment: No, if  I have to mark 70% as complete and 30% as pending then below 70 the diamond should be there

Comment: @Geeky I have added a custom handler to set progress using HTML input. Hope this helps. If this satisfies your condition consider upvoting. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can't we do this without placeholder? Actually, I just want to do this with hardcoded data.

Comment: Just call _updateProgressDOM(num)_ with a percentage number  you wish. That will inturn update your progressbar status.